# How do i add node js modules to my simple project that i worked on just by js and html and css?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is the problem:
I have a project that I worked on using basic js and css and html. Now I need some nodeJS functionalities (fs) which allow me to write and save modifications on JSON data files.
How can I add nodeJS?

Comment: You can't. NodeJS is a separate host environment in which JavaScript runs, separate from the browser. You can't interact with the file system from the browser (except in limited scenarios), so you'll need to use a web server and ajax (or HTML forms) to get the data back and forth from the browser. That web server and the code within could be written in JavaScript and run on NodeJS, but not like you're thinking.

Comment: Also, click on the tag name here on Stack Overflow, then click on "Learn more..." and you'll find a ton of information about NodeJS.

Comment: thanks, i'll see. may be i need to switch to database